# Nothing renders in connected screen apart from cursor

Tags: display, 22.04, kde, plasma, ubuntu-studio

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and connected another screen to my new laptop. When I try to drag a window to the other screen, I can see the cursor but not the window. Even when I right click on the other screen I do not see anything. The only change I made that might be affecting rendering behaviour was to increase global scale to 200% on the primary laptop screen because everything was tiny. I changed global scale back to 100% and it made no difference to the described behaviour.

I have posted this question in the Ubuntu Studio chat/forum, but they do not believe this is a distro specific issue. From the discussion, it is most likely a broader issue with KDE Plasma, as they make no changes to the source code. The base Ubuntu Studio configs don't touch scaling.

I am not sure how to fix the issue - there are probably just some drivers I need to install. If I can't find a solution soon I will probably need to switch to another distro.

By default Ubuntu Studio uses X11. From the [release notes](https://ubuntustudio.org/category/development/):

> "OBS Studio is upgraded to version 27.2.3 and works with Wayland sessions. While Wayland is not currently the default, it is available as unsupported and experimental."

The machine is also fitted with an nvidia graphics card which might be affecting the behaviour.

Comment: No, there are no drivers to install unless you have Nvidia and the proprietary drivers weren't automatically installed. It isn't clear whether you're using X11 or Wayland. Please [edit] the question to clarify and while at that also post hardware specifications.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working (for now) by switching over to Wayland.

I think Wayland is supported with Ubuntu Studio but nonetheless I still ran the command

`apt-get install -y plasma-workspace-wayland` 
which seemed to installed a few extra packages.

Switching from X11 to Wayland can be done at the login screen. It was a bit difficult for me to see the selector because all the text is super small for some reason. I have also (unsuccessfully) tried to change some configs to ensure wayland is set as default.

TLDR: switch to wayland